# Should I reinstall the OS after restoring from time machine?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, memory, restore, crash

A while back, my MacBook Pro died. It was an older machine (2007 I think), with a Core 2 Duo processor. I was doing regular backups through Time Machine. I bought a I7 MBP, and re-staged the new system by restoring from the Time Machine backup.

The performance of the new machine is not quite what I expected. It crashes fairly frequently, and seems to page-out memory even though I installed 16GB of RAM.

Would it be worthwhile to reinstall the OS? Is it possible that the OS restored from Time Machine is not taking full advantage of the new machine's processor and RAM?

Answer (score 1):

Though any Mac OS install includes all the bits needed to run most modern Macs, it's generally helpful to build a fresh install with a new computer and processor. I find it's best to do a fresh install (erasing the drive) and then migrate the user from the Time Machine backup. The user migration process is amazingly thorough.